# Multiple Stored Procedures in 1 Transaction with Foreign Key

Tags: c#, sql

trying to run multiple stored procedures in 1 transaction. If one fails Id like to roll all the changes back. The problem is without committing the first , the foreign key requirements are not met for the 2nd because it uses the ID of the 1st.

Is there any way to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the SP are nested one inside other? Correct?

Comment: Not at the moment they are not. Would that work for rolling it back if they were nested?

Comment: If you manage correctly them you can. But you surely can also in this way.

Comment: SQL Server or mysql?

Comment: Sql Server. The problem I'm having is I have to commit the some first to run others or they fail due to foreign key restraint.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

1) Manage your procedure under transaction : `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (I suppose you just do it)

2) Manage the errors and if one of them goes in error you only need to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. You can insert a `TRY'N'CATCH` and do the `ROLLBACK` in `catch` statement.

Let me know